# Adding a row (not a column) of a type (checkbox,dropdown) in datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a datagridview that is only two or three rows long. It has 7 text columns, one for each day of the week (Monday - Sunday). I'm creating a scheduler, so basically on the left side I have added text to the row headers to assign to it. I.e. Enabled (let's say for Tuesday), start time and end time. This allows the user to schedule as need be.

Here's a picture of it right now:
[image]

What I want to do is possibly change the enabled row, or the start/end time to a particular type. So the enabled will be a checkbox and the start/end times will be drop down menus instead of these text boxes.

My question is, what's the "best" way to add a row of a certain type? Obviously columns are done easily, but is there a common method for a row type other than looping through and adding individual cells of that type to the datagridview?

Comment: just flip the row/column layout so that the Days are rows and you dont have to do anything special

Comment: But what's the fun in that?? (It's a requested GUI format that I'm trying to work around)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of each cell can only be pre-determined by the column, not the row.  As a result, you're going to have to add each cell individually.  You can actually put a cell of any type anywhere you want.  You simply create a cell of the desired type and assign it to the `Item` property of the grid, e.g.

```
myDataGridView(columnIndex, rowIndex) = newCell
```

You will simply have to use a `For` loop to do that for each valid column index with a single row index.  Note that you'll have to create a new cell for each column, not reuse the same one.